# MVC web site: localhost page can’t be found http error 404

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm developing a Asp.net MVC Core 2.2 web site in IIS. 
The IIS website that hosts my MVC Core project has been created correctly. My project generates correctly a PDF file. Usually, I just use a jquery function to open that PDF file in browser:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CreatePDF", "MyApiController", new { area= "MyArea" })',            
            dataType: 'json',                
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,            
            data: JSON.stringify(Filtro),
            success: function (d) {

                if (d.success == true) {
                    var item = d.data;
                    var pageurl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + 'Temporal/' + item.PDFName;
                    window.open(pageurl, '_blank');

                }

            },
```

However, I just realized that this MVC Core web site doesn't allow to open any PDF or txt or jpg or whatever file in browser and instead output this message:

```
localhost page can’t be found 
http error 404
```

My question is:

In a MVC Core web site, how should I open a PDF file in browser from Controller

```
        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<BE_Reporte> CreatePDF(BE_Reporte c)
        {

            BL_Reporte b = new BL_Reporte();

            try
            {
                c = b.CreatePDF(c);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    data = c,
                    success = true,
                    Message = "PDF created OK"

                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            finally
            {
                b.Dispose(); b = null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The `Controller` suffix isn’t needed when generating a URL.

Comment: What are you hoping this will do?: `[Route("[action]")]`

Comment: Share us the network tab, which request return 404?

Answer (score 1):

The generated Url for `'@Url.Content("~/")' + 'Temporal/' + item.PDFName;` will be something like `/Temporal/Test.pdf`. For this request url, you need to place the `Test.pdf` in the place `CoreMVC2_2\wwwroot\Temporal\Test.pdf`.

If you place the `Temporal` in other folder except wwwroot, it is recommended to move it to `wwwroot`, otherwise, you need to configure the [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).

And for client side, you may need to try code below:

```
var pageurl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + 'Temporal/' + 'Test.pdf';
console.log(pageurl);
var newWindow = window.open("", '_blank');
newWindow.location = pageurl;
```

Comment: Edward, thank you for your insight regarding the wwwroot folder.  I had attempted to make use of several other suggestions but all had failed to point out the need to nest my new folder under the wwwroot folder.  A simple oversight on my part that cost me much more time to resolve than it should have.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the 404 Error says the server did not find the resource you requested.  First try to place a break-point at the beginning of the controller action CreatePDF. Then change your attribute routing to [HttpPost("[action]")] and remove the leading [Route("[action]")] call as it might be causing a routing error.
Also, try and add [FromBody] before your parameter.

```
...([FromBody] BE_Reporte ...)
```

Also you can use `<iframe>` HTML tag to display a pdf file or use `<embed>`
as noted here: [Load Generated PDF Data into IFRAME on ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425989/load-generated-pdf-data-into-iframe-on-asp-net-mvc)